# tkinter overrideredirect stops entry working

Tags: python, html, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to create a "Borderless" window in python and my code works without overrideredirect, however when I use this the input is disallowed. I can not click into the Entry box

*This is the code which needs to be figured out, it is currently in a function and there is another 500 lines of code to go with it :D *

```
newWindow = tkinter.Tk()

w = 300
h = 400

ws = 1024
hs = 768
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
newWindow.configure(background="#2E393D")


newWindow.overrideredirect(True)

frame = tkinter.Frame(newWindow)
name = tkinter.Label(newWindow, background="#1c1c1c", width=2, height=4)
name.pack()
global outputl
global inputl
inputl = tkinter.StringVar()
outputl = tkinter.StringVar()
def nomic(empty):
    reply = inputl.get()
    inputl.set("")
    mainProcess(reply)


if way == "a":
    import speech_recognition as sr
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            reply = r.recognize_google(audio)
            mainProcess(reply)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            backCreateFile("I did not understand that !")

else:
    inputBox = tkinter.Entry(frame, textvariable=inputl, width=40,foreground="#2E393D", background="white", font=("Ubuntu", 13))
    inputBox.bind("<Return>", nomic)
    inputBox.pack(fill="x") 
outputLabel = tkinter.Label(newWindow, textvariable=outputl)
outputLabel.config( background="#2E393D", foreground="white", wraplength=280, pady=10, font=("Ubuntu", 13))
outputLabel.pack(fill="x") 
weatherV = tkinter.StringVar()
weatherV.set("Current Weather - " + status)
weatherLabel = tkinter.Label(newWindow, justify="left", textvariable=weatherV, background="#2E393D", foreground="white", font=("Ubuntu", 13), pady=7).pack(fill="x")
tempV = tkinter.StringVar()
tempV.set("Current Temperature - " + str(ctemp))
tempLabel = tkinter.Label(newWindow, justify="left", textvariable=tempV, background="#2E393D", foreground="white", font=("Ubuntu", 13), pady=7).pack(fill="x")
frame.pack()
```

Comment: What platform are you running on? OSX?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and replace your example code with an MCVE

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and was able to get around it by using

`root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)`

This makes the GUI fill the screen completely, creating a 'borderless' window, but still allows for interaction with the entry widgets and setting focus.

Answer (score 0):

I created an account just so i could answer this.

delete the line with your overridedirect statement and replace it with:

```
root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash');
```

^ You are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Here is minimal code that works on Windows with Python 3.6 and tk 8.6.    The popup is in its default position, the upper left corner the screen.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tag = tk.Label(root, text='Popup entry contents: ')
var = tk.StringVar(root, 'var')
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)
tag.pack(side='left')
label.pack(side='left')

pop = tk.Toplevel(root)
pop.overrideredirect(True)
entry = tk.Entry(pop, textvariable=var)
entry.pack()
#pop.lift()  # Needed? for tk 8.5.18+, not for 8.6
```

Test this on your system, and if it works, figure out what you did differently in your code.